# Group action on subspace of $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, group-actions

I need to find a totally discontinuous $D_4$ action on $S^\infty\subset L^2([0,1])$.

Background: Here $L^2([0,1])=\{\text{measurable }f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{C} : \int |f|^2<\infty\}$,  $S^\infty:=\{f\in L^2([0,1]) : ||f||_{L^2}=1\}$ and $D_4$ is the dihedral group with 8 elements. To say $D_4$ acts "totally disconinuously" on $S^\infty$ is to say that for all $x\in S^\infty$, there exists open $U\ni x$ such that $gU\cap U\neq \emptyset \Rightarrow g=e$. Basically, this just means that every non-identity element moves every element in $S^\infty$.

My attempt: So $D_4$ is generated by $r$ and $s$ where $r^2=s^4=(rs)^2=e$. The natural choice for the action of $r$ on $S^\infty$ is $rf\to -f$. This map is (lipschitz) continuous and clearly moves every element. Now I was trying to find transformation of order 4 that moves every element of $S^\infty$ which also satisfies $(rs)^2=e$. Here are some things I have tried: Some possible actions of order 4 are $sf=if$ , $s f=g$ where $g(t)=f(1-t)$, $sf=\overline{f}$. But all of these commute with $r$. I then tried to do one thing to $f$ on half of the interval and something else to $f$ on the other half, but nothing that I could find works. I am wondering now If I chose the wrong action for $r$ but $rf=-f$ feels to me like the only natural choice. I would appreciate any sort of hint!

Edit: the maps $sf=g$ and $sf=\overline{f}$ specified above are not order 4...I meant something more like $sf=ig$ and conjugating then switching the real and imaginary parts.

Second edit: It is possible that this cannot be done... I have my doubts

Comment: I also have serious doubts. $D_4$ is the symmetry group of the square $[-1,1]^2$ in the plane, where $r$ is a reflection and $s$ is a rotation by $\pi/2$. Thus $D_4$ acts on the square, but this action is not totally discontinuous. I do not know whether this is really relevant to your question, but it is a hint that it may be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer:
Take $rf=- \bar{f}$ and $sf=if$, then they are order $2$ and $4$ respectively and do not commute. In fact:
$$ s^{-1}r(f) = s^{-1}(-\bar{f}) = i\bar{f} = r(if) = rs(f) $$
So they generate a copy of the dihedral group. However, the action is not totally discontinuous since $r$ has the imaginary functions as fixed points. I haven't found a way to improve this and am not sure this would be of interest to you.

Comment: You should take $sf = if$ (order $4$) and $rf = -\overline f$ (order $2$). By the way, $rf = \overline f$ is also a valid variant.

Comment: @PaulFrost Noted and edited.